# How can I find multiple line matches in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

With the following table

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
    A varchar(2),
    B varchar(2)
);

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES 
    ('aa', 'm'), ('aa', 'n'),
    ('bb', 'n'), ('bb', 'o'),
    ('cc', 'n'), ('cc', 'o'),
    ('dd', 'c'), ('dd', 'a'), ('dd', 'r'),
    ('ee', 'a'), ('ee', 'c'), ('ee', 'r')

A   | B
----+----
aa  | m
aa  | n
bb  | n
bb  | o
cc  | n
cc  | o
dd  | c
dd  | a
dd  | r
ee  | a
ee  | c
ee  | r
```

How can I select and group the values in A that match all the coresponding values in B. For example bb and cc make up a group because they both contain 'n' and 'o'.

So the result would be

```
Group | A
----------
1     | bb
1     | cc
2     | dd
2     | ee
```

Comment: Is there a maximum size of the group (you have 2,3 in your example)

Comment: There is no maximum size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach: it first calculates the matching "sets", where a set is a group of two `A`'s which match.  Then it calculate the "head", or the lowest `A` for sets in the same group.  Using `dense_rank` you can number the heads, and then join back on the list of sets to create a list of all set members.

Query at [SE Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/109691/).

```
; with  groups  as
        (
        select  distinct A
        from    @t
        )
,       vals as
        (
        select  distinct B
        from    @t
        )
,       sets as
        (
        select  g1.A as g1
        ,       g2.A as g2
        from    groups g1
        join    groups g2
        on      g1.A < g2.A
        cross join
                vals v
        left join
                @t v1
        on      g1.A = v1.A
                and v.B = v1.B
        left join
                @t v2
        on      g2.A = v2.A
                and v.B = v2.B
        group by
                g1.A
        ,       g2.A
        having  count(case when isnull(v1.B,'') <> isnull(v2.B,'') then 1 end) = 0
        )
,       heads as
        (
        select  s1.g1
        ,       s1.g2
        ,       head.head
        from    sets s1
        cross apply
                (
                select  min(g1) as head
                from    sets s2
                where   s1.g2 = s2.g2
                ) head
        )
select  distinct dense_rank() over (order by h.head)
,       g.g
from    (
        select  distinct head
        from    heads
        ) h
left join
        (
        select  g1 as g
        ,       head
        from    heads
        union all
        select  g2
        ,       head
        from    heads
        ) g
on      h.head = g.head
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but the performance isn't as good as I need it. It will give me a great place to start though.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2008 has the `EXCEPT` and `INTERSECT` functions, which could be used. This isn't in exactly the format that you wanted and I can't speak to performance against large data sets, but perhaps it will give you a starting point.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    T1.A,
    T2.A
FROM
    T1 AS T1
INNER JOIN T1 AS T2 ON T2.A > T1.A
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT
        B
    FROM
        T1 AS T3
    WHERE
        T3.A = T1.A
    EXCEPT
    SELECT
        B
    FROM
        T1 AS T4
    WHERE
        T4.A = T2.A
    ) AND
    NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT
        B
    FROM
        T1 AS T3
    WHERE
        T3.A = T2.A
    EXCEPT
    SELECT
        B
    FROM
        T1 AS T4
    WHERE
        T4.A = T1.A
    )
```

Depending on your data, you could also generate some concatenated strings with delimiters and specific ordering within the string and then compare those.

Comment: +1 The concatenation approach would perform much better, although the set approach is more fun :)

Answer (score 0):

The relational operator you require is [division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29), popularly known as ["the supplier who supplies all parts"](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/772076.htm).

Actually, division comes in about eight flavours and the SQL language has implemented none of them directly. However, they can all be recreated using existing SQL constructs: see [this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) for the more popular ones. Things to consider include: exact division or with remainder; how to handle an empty divisor.